Android floating window over other apps in Expo / Expo Modules API
I'm working on an Android app, a central feature of which will be a floating modal window (SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW I think is the associated permission) that can display over the home screen or other apps, and be triggered via a shortcut. I'd like to use Expo if I can for this project, since my background is in web development and I'm negligibly familiar with native Android, but I haven't yet figured out whether it's a thing Expo can do.
I've poked around online for examples, finding some nearby things that seem promising, but no examples of this in particular. I've tried my hand at implementing this myself via expo modules, but I quickly found myself down a rabbit hole of little issues to figure out, so I wanted to double check first that the thing I'm trying to do is possible.
Can this be accomplished within Expo, and if so could you give me a rough scaffolding for how one might accomplish it? Thank you!
